# How to use v-for to render a table using vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I've an array that look like this:

```
sales = [
 [{'Year': 2018, 'Month': 01, 'Sale'; 512}, {'Year': 2018, 'Month': 02, 'Sale'; 1025}, ....],
 [{'Year': 2017, 'Month': 01, 'Sale'; 155}, {'Year': 2017, 'Month': 02, 'Sale'; 12}, ....]
]
```

i would like to show it in a table using vue:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>2018</th>
      <th>2017</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(sale,i) in sales" :key="i">
       <th scope="row">{{ ??? }}</th> //Month
       <td>{{ ??? }}</td> //currentYear.Sale
       <td>{{ ??? }}</td> //previousYear.Sale
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

unfortunately i don't know how to iterate through my sales array to show in every table row sale of the current year and the previous year.

Comment: Please refer following link of vue documentation, its clearly explained   

 https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for

Answer (score 18):

```
<div id="app">
  <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>2018</th>
      <th>2017</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(sale,i) in sales[0]" :key="i">
       <th scope="row">{{ sale.Month  }}</th>  
       <td>{{ sale.Sale }}</td> 
       <td>{{ sales[1][i].Sale }}</td>  
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    sales: [
        [{'Year': 2018, 'Month': 01, 'Sale': 512}, {'Year': 2018, 'Month': 02, 'Sale': 1025}],
            [{'Year': 2017, 'Month': 01, 'Sale': 155}, {'Year': 2017, 'Month': 02, 'Sale': 12}]
    ]
  } 
})
```

example https://jsfiddle.net/mcqwtdgr/

Comment: i need in my table data the sale element not the year.

Comment: I changed the answer