# VueJS, creating a contact list directory using tables yet latest rows overwrite entries in other tables

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I new to VueJS and I am trying to create a contact list directory using tables to group names alphabetically. For example,

| A |
| --- |
| Alexander, Y PhoneCode: ### |

| B |
| --- |
| Bufford, D PhoneCode: ### |

|   C   |
|-------|
|Cuzco, C PhoneCode: ###|
etc.

I am building the table using javascript by looping through an array of objects of employees

I want to use VueJS to build the tables and use v-for to go through the array of employee objects and place them under the correct table. This is the .js file.

```
let empSet2 = new Set();
let arr2 = [];
let temp2 = [];
let element2;

const containerAdd = document.querySelector('#vueBody2');
const createList = new Vue({
    el: '#vueBody2',
    created() {
        console.log('created');
        this.checkLastNames();
        this.createHeader();
    },
    data: function(){
        return{
        employees,
        empSet2,
        arr2,
        temp2: [],
        };
    },
    methods: {
// gets the last names of the employees from the array and puts the first index of the last name into an array
        checkLastNames(){
            employees.map(letter3 => letter3.lastName.slice(0,1))
                                   .sort()
                                   .forEach(lastNameLetter => empSet2.add(lastNameLetter));
            arr2 = [...empSet2];
        },

// goes through the array of header elements
       createHeader() {
        arr2.forEach((element) => {
            const tableTest1 = document.createElement("table");
            tableTest1.classList.add('table1');
            containerAdd.appendChild(tableTest1);
             const tableHeadCreate = document.createElement("thead");
            tableHeadCreate.innerHTML = `<thead colspan="5" style="width:100%"><tr colspan="5" class="directoryHeader"><td class="tableCell1"><h2>${element.toUpperCase()}</h2></td></tr></thead>`;
            tableTest1.appendChild(tableHeadCreate);
            let tbodyCreate = document.createElement("tbody");
            this.temp2 = this.updateTemp2(element);
            tbodyCreate.innerHTML = `
            <tr v-for="(row, index) in temp2" :key="row.empId" :row="row">
                <td>{{row.lastName}}, {{row.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{row.phoneCode}}</td>
            </tr>
                                    `;
        tableHeadCreate.appendChild(tbodyCreate);
        });
        },
        updateTemp2(element) {
            console.log('updateTemp2 called ');
            return employees.filter(lastname => lastname.lastName.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() === element.toUpperCase());
        },
```

This is the html

```
    <div class="row" style="max-width: 1750px; margin-left: 2px;" id="vueBody2">
    </div>
```

My output is essentially:

| A |
| --- |
| Cuzco, Caitlyn ### |

| B |
| --- |
| Cuzco, Caitlyn ### |

| C |
| --- |
| Cuzco, Caitlyn ### |

A solution I have tried is to create a v-if to check if the current first index of row.lastName of the array of objects matched the current header letter but that has not worked as I can't pass the current header letter into a function.

```
           element2 = element;
            tbodyCreate.innerHTML = `
            <tr v-for="(row, index) in employees" :key="row.empId" :row="row">
                <template v-if="compareIndexes(row.lastName, element2)">
                <td>{{row.lastName}}, {{row.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{row.phoneCode}}</td>
                </template>
            </tr>
                                    `;

 compareIndexes: function(checkArr, element){
            console.log('in compareIndexes');
            console.log(element);
            if(checkArr.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() === element){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },
```

The console.log(element) gives me undefined

One thing I noticed is that the second log statement ('temp 2 called') is only triggering after the C element is created. I suspect that the previous 2 innerHTML statements are being overwritten by the loop in the C element. My thought while building the method was that it would get the last names that started with A, create the table rows with A last names and then move onto the B last names etc. My solution in vanilla JS would be to use a map but I don't believe that would work with VueJS.

EDIT: Just wanted to mention to anyone stubbling across this post that I managed to figure out my solution. I used two v-fors, one in the div before a table and one in the tbody section.

Comment: The code you're showing is not at all the "Vue" way to do this. Vue (like the other framework) give you lots of "tools" to manipulate the DOM (like rendering a list like you're trying to do). 
Maybe you should invest more time in understanding basic vue concepts in official doc (like making async call and rendering data  in a `v-for` as its basically what you need)
You could also refer to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963481/how-to-use-v-for-to-render-a-table-using-vue-js

Comment: Okay, I will read through that question and doing more research into vue and into the concepts you are referring to.

Comment: I figured it out, I needed a course to explain it in depth but I think I am starting to get it

Comment: Great  do not hesitate to update your question with new code snippets from what you learnt if you're still blocked